# Multifile Rust project

Tags: rust

My Rust project consists of two files: `main.rs` and `structs.rs` - the structs file just contains a pile of structures such as

```
pub struct Area {
    width: f32,
    length: f32
}
```

In my `main.rs` file, I have the following:

```
mod structs;
use structs::*;
```

then my `fn main()` code (this creates a variable to store the structs and then uses a couple of `println!` lines to output the contents of the variable).

When I run cargo run on the source, I'm getting a pile of throwback such as

```
src/main.rs:27:26: 27:62 error: field `width` of struct `structs::Area` is private [E0451]
src/main.rs:27             window_area: Area {width: 0.9f32, length: 1.1f32},
```

Do I need to be defining every field within my struct as being pub or is there something I'm missing here?

I don't really want to create a crate for such a simple POC, but this is driving me mad. I can get the code to work using the `include!()` macro.

Comment: `pub` is explicit in Rust. If you want to access the field externally, you need `pub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Your struct fields are private by default - the scope of which is limited to within the module that it is defined.

So, within your `structs.rs` file/module, you would be able to use the `width` and `length` fields without troubles. However, if you want them to be accessible from outside of the `structs` module, you'll need to declare them as public (via `pub`). That, or declare methods on your type that can manipulate the fields themselves (encapsulate them).

Here is an example showing all 3 scenarios ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fab99bb52bec5a9cd007ac0f90cf38f3&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
mod working {
    pub struct Object {
        pub name: String
    }
}

mod notworking {
    pub struct Object {
        name: String
    }

    impl Object {
        pub fn something(&self) {
            println!("Name is: {}", self.name); // <--- perfectly fine to use a private 
                                                // field within the same module
        }
    }
}

struct Object {
    name: String
}

fn main() {
    let same_module = Object{ name: "Same module".to_string() };
    let working_module = working::Object{ name: "Working module".to_string() };
    let notworking_module = notworking::Object{ name: "Not working module".to_string() };
}
```

One where the private field is in the same module, one where the private field is in another module and one where a public field is in another module. Note that making the `name` field public in the `notworking` module will make the code compile.